# MySQL User with Roles, Role specific fields?

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, database-design

> I have an application where a User can be a Supplier or a Shop.
>   Now these 2 roles have very different role-specific fields..

**Basically, a Shop can make Orders to Suppliers.. So a Shop can make Orders and a Supplier will receive those Orders.**

Where would I put these fields for good practice?

- Add them all on the User class, with nullable types (doesn't seem right!)
- Create a different class for each Role. So we have a Supplier class with a user_id and Shop class with a user_id, I would have to query these fields using $user->supplier->field or $user->shop->field...

Neither of these seems like thé way to go. Any idea's? 
Thank you!

Comment: I think this really depends on the context of your application. Try providing more information about the rest of the application as it would help out determining the right way.

Comment: A Shop can make Orders to Suppliers.. So a Shop can make Orders and a Supplier will receive those Orders.

Comment: Sketch out both ways, _including_ the `SELECTs`.  When finished, you will answer your own question.  (That is, still not enough info to advise you.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to stick with a single `users` table. You can have a Supplier model and a Shop model (with `suppliers` and `shops` tables).

Then in the `config/auth.php` file, you can set up a new auth provider using the Eloquent driver but with a different model. You can then assign those providers to any new guards that you create.

You can read more about authentication and authorisation here: 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authorization

**Edit**

After it was mentioned in the comments about polymorphic relations, I think that would apply better for this type of relationship (multiple types of users, each with own set of fields).

Read more here:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations

Comment: This will work if the polymorphism only applies to authentication. If there are other polymorphic aspects, for example: "Orders can belong to a Supplier or Shop", Laravel supports polymorphic relations (see: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations)

Comment: I was thinking about that option. But isn't it to much overhead to do that? The whole idea of Roles then doesn't apply anymore, right?

Comment: and what if an admin role appears? That can see all orders, then I have to  create another auth provider? right?

Comment: I've amended my answer. I agree with Jeffrey that polymorphic relations would be helpful.

Comment: Thank you, So a Supplier can have Orders, but a Shop as well.. and they're both Users.. is that a case of polymorphism you think?

Comment: @Notflip yes I think that is a case of polymorphism and whilst it might be a bit trickier setting it up, it should work fine. Google search for "Laravel polymorphism SEO example" for a working example.

Answer (score 1):

Can a user have multiple shops or supply multiples? Your second option seems fine.

**User** hasMany: supplier, shop
- id
- name

**Supplier** belongsTo, hasOne: user
- id
- user_id
- fields_supplier

**Shop** belongsTo, hasOne: user
- id
- user_id
- fields_shop

`$user->supplier->fields_supplier;

$user->shop->fields_shop;

$supplier->user->name;

$shop->user->name;`

--
If you had more info on how you wanted it to work, it would help.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The issue now would be, both a Supplier and a Shop have orders, the shop sends them and the supplier recieves them.. But if I would call $user->orders.. or would you do it as follows: $user->shop->orders and $user->supplier->orders

Comment: Is it a flow like: 1. Shop creates Order, 2. Order becomes available to Suppliers, 3. Supplier takes that Order and fulfills it?

Comment: In that case, I would consider adding 'created by' (shop_id) and 'fulfilled by' (supplier_id)  columns to Order. Those columns can then become the relative keys?

Answer (score 1):

"Supplier" is a role played by a "Party" ("Individual" or "Organization")

Your store may get a Catalog from a Supplier, and may Request Quotes from them.

Your store creates "Purchase Orders" and sends them to the Supplier, and they send you "Order Responses"

A Supplier is not a user. You could create "User"s for their employees though

Why not just use an existing ERP like Odoo?